Command in R using edit function
So I was using this command in R
edit(as.data.frame(NULL))

However I am not able to understand like how to save this data file. Everytime I run the command the data file disappears
Evertime I run this command, my laptop is getting hanged and the data set dissapears.

df <- edit(as.data.frame(NULL)). You have to assign the command.

You can assign the result of edit to an object and then save it using any standard method such as saveRDS() or write.csv():
df <- edit(name = data.frame())

write.csv(df, "df.csv")

Created on 2024-06-01 with reprex v2.1.0
